# Disable filter in query parameter using dstore Rest

Tags: javascript, dojo, dstore

Because I use more dgrid objects then native dojo objects that interacts with a store, I want to switch to dstore instead of dojo.store.rest.
But when I use `dstore` with adapter for the live-search (FilteringSelect) the query parameters got modified in a way that breaks my api: e.g. I type "foo" it sends a request to

`/api?name=match=foo*`

But I want:

`/api?name=foo*`

Like it is with `dojo/store/rest`.
I think it comes from Filter class in dstore.
Is there a way to disable this Filter?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I deal with this, along with setting some defaults I use

```
define([
  'dojo/_base/declare',
  'dojo/query',
  'dstore/Rest'
],
function (declare, query, Rest) {

   var csrfHeader = query('meta[name="_csrf_header"]')[0].content,
       csrfToken = query('meta[name="_csrf"]')[0].content,
       headers = {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
       };

    headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;


return declare('app.store.rest', [ Rest ], {

       sortParam: 'sort',
       rangeStartParam: 'offset',
       rangeCountParam: 'limit',
       ascendingPrefix: '%2B',
       descendingPrefix: '%2D',
       accepts: 'application/json',
       headers: headers,

       _renderFilterParams: function (filter) {
           var _filter = this.inherited(arguments);
           for(var i=0; i<_filter.length; i++) {
               _filter[i] = _filter[i].replace('match=', '').replace('*', '');
           }
           return _filter;
       }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve this behavior, I had to add a modified version of _renderFilterParams:

```js
var store = new Rest({
    target: '/api',
    _renderFilterParams: function (filter) {
        var type = filter.type;
        var args = filter.args;
        if (!type)
            return [''];
        if (type === 'string')
            return [args[0]];
        return [encodeURIComponent(args[0]) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(args[1])];
    }
});
```